# Multiple GeoJSon markers loading from url not showing

Tags: javascript, json, mapbox

I'm trying to make a website that constantly updates the location of a group of people. I'm using mapbox for this.

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.12.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9uYXRoYW52b3MiLCJhIjoiY2lpMXJlZmtiMDBlOXRybTBtYmtyNTh0cCJ9.ipvKe_0qEvR18atA-3wggQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8',
    center: [5.863, 51.822],
    zoom: 15
});

var url = 'http://195.***.**.19/test/tempPaths.json';
var source = new mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource({
  data: url
});

window.setInterval(function() {
  source.setData(url);
}, 1000);

map.on('style.load', function() {
  map.addSource("markers", source);
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "markers",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "markers",
    "paint": {
      "circle-radius": 10,
      "circle-color": "#ff0000"
    }
  });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The url is pointing to a file containing this:

```
{
  "type": "geojson",
  "data": {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [5.857907820447556, 51.82389690205782]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Person1"
      }
    },{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [5.862187668426313, 51.82399055633142]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Person2"
      }
    },{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [5.866520068371708, 51.82419298727476]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": "Person3"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

The file is updated every second. With each update the coordinates change.
The map is supposed to show each spot on the map, but it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapboxgl.GeoJSONSource` expects a valid GeoJSON object or an url which returns one. You've encapsulated the GeoJSON collection in another object. Remove it and you're good to go:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [5.857907820447556, 51.82389690205782]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Person1"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [5.862187668426313, 51.82399055633142]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Person2"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [5.866520068371708, 51.82419298727476]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Person3"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much for the fast reply.